# Real time application with CakePHP

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cakephp, firebase

I'm currently have an app built with CakePHP, it's a fantasy football site. However, I built the draft platform really poorly, it's essentially javascript on a timer that just updates the the view every few seconds.

I've been looking into Firebase + Angularjs for doing the draft in real time but I don't really understand Firebase in depth. It just stores everything as JSON? Which I don't think would be the right path since a relational database helps a lot with having a list of players, stats, plus teams that have associations to the players, different leagues, etc. Unless firebase can be made to work with a relation database, I'm not sure if it's for me (Or I could just have a poor understanding of it).

What are some other technologies that might be helpful with real time data? I've looked at node.js, pusher, and socket.io but I'm not sure which one would play the best with CakePHP.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perfectly fine using CakePHP and a relational DB to serve JSON and act as a RESTful backend and use AngularJS as frontend.

Socket.io is a completely different approach as it uses Websockets and not REST. You would have to implement a Websocket server using [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) with CakePHP.

I recommend you to learn about the different technologies first and then make a decision.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm trying to learn about these different technologies right now! I've learned that I just have to do long polling and that way I can keep all clients up to date in real time, but I'm worried about having too many threads going at once. I'm also currently looking at using firebase for the actual draft and once the draft is finished, send over the results to the DB.